# Why is the error function in my `tryCatch` statement not preventing an error?

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to run a `tryCatch` on a t-test that prints any errors as warnings, then returns NA.

```
tryCatch(t.test(x, y)[['p.value']], error = function(e) {warning(e); NA})
```

What's supposed to happen is that if any of my t.tests are run on bad data, I return NA so that the whole batch isn't gummed up (I'm mapping this over a large number of variable pairs). What happens instead is that I get the error. Full stop.

Is there a correct way to get the behavior I want? That is, returns the result of the T test if there's no error, and NA if there is an error?

EDIT: could not reproduce dummy example when I tried it again. But error continues in the real case. When I follow the trace it says the error ultimately emanates from `base::warning` which is weird. Also, when I replace my error function in `tryCatch` with `error = function(e) NA` the whole thing runs perfectly.

But also, recreating the actual error that causes problems doesn't actually replicate the problem! I get NA and the error comes out as a warning!

```
> tryCatch(expr = {t.test(c(NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA))}, error = function(e) {warning(e); NA})
[1] NA
Warning message:
In t.test.default(c(NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA)) : not enough 'x' observations
```

What gives?!?

Comment: Are you saving the results of the `tryCatch` somewhere? I'm not sure I can replicate the behavior you are seeing. I see NA values being returned when there's an error. What happens if you run `tryCatch(stop("test!"), error = function(e) {NA})`? Are you still getting an error? Have you tried this in a fresh R session?

Comment: Hmm, I can't replicate the dummy example in a fresh R session either. But the error is still happening *in situ*.

Comment: Your running environment must have overwritten the default `tryCatch` or `warning` functions. Unless you can make the problem reproducible, it's going to be very hard to know what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```r
x <- 1:5
y <- c("a", "b", "c")

tryCatch(
  t.test(x, y)[['p.value']], 
  error = function(e) {warning(e); NA}
)
#> Warning in mean.default(y): argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in var(y): NAs introduced by coercion
#> Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant"): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

tryCatch(
  t.test(x, y)[['p.value']], 
  warning = function(w) NA,
  error = function(e) {warning(e); NA}
)
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>